# Firefox build with LTO failure

Tags: firefox, lto

I was trying to build firefox with lto, but the building is failed due to a linker error. This is the error I am getting:

```
0:01.34 DEBUG: /tmp/conftest-79f19c.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
0:01.34 DEBUG: clang-3.9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
0:01.34 DEBUG: configure: failed program was:
0:01.34 DEBUG:
0:01.34 DEBUG: #line 2758 "configure"
0:01.34 DEBUG: #include "confdefs.h"
0:01.34 DEBUG:
0:01.34 DEBUG: main(){return(0);}
0:01.34 DEBUG: configure: error: installation or configuration problem: C compiler cannot create executables.
```

Comment: please provide the error as code, not as image. Also could you provide more information, like compiler, build environment, ...?

Comment: @Florian sorry about that, edited now.